# Override 415 response in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.net Core 2.1, I want to return a Json response along with Status code 415 instead of just 415 returned by default.

To achieve this I am using a resource filter:

```
public class MediaTypeResouceFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 415)
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult() { StatusCode = 415, Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse), ContentType = "application/json" };
        }
    }
}
```

In debugging, I see that context.Result is being overrided successfully but postman gets only 415 with no Json response.

In case I put:

```
context.Result = new ContentResult() { StatusCode = 415, Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse), ContentType = "application/json" };
```

inside OnResourceExecuting instead of OnResourceExecuted, it works as I wish but the thing is that I can't check for status code before executing resource.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

can you try this?

```
public class MediaTypeResouceFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 415)
            {
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "this is custom message" });
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
                context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can get a 415 Status Code and body data is: `{"data":"this is custom message"}`

Actually `OnResourceExecuted` fires too late but you can modify the body for your custom message

Comment: This might walk around it sometimes. But be careful when you have already set a response . Let's say you're sending a response of 415 within an action with a content of `11111111111111111111111AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDD`. Since the content-length doesn't match, you'll get an error.

Comment: Yes sure I understand. This would be dangerous in some cases. If we really want to response a custom message like this question, be careful to add more business

Comment: Well, although I don't think there's an elegant way to do that by "adding more business", I vote up for your  quick and short walkaround.

Answer (score 2):

I think using the middleware component is a good choise. This is the Invoke method of the middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    Exception exception = null;
    try {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        //try handling exception stuff...
    }

    //try handling 415 code stuff...
    if(context.Response.StatusCode==415){
        var yourJsonObj = new { Blah = "blah..." };
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourJsonObj);
        //context.Response.StatusCode = 200; //You can change the StatusCode here
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the workflow by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) :

[image: filter execution workflow]

The method of `IResourceFilter::OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)` **runs after the Result execution**. Since the result execution has already finished, you can make no change to result.

Comment: I leave a comment here  because I don't know whether there's a nice approach to replace the body according to status code within a filter.  There's no API to peek `StatusCode` before the `IActionResult` execution.  But if somebody would like to do that, a better place is to replace the Result before the Result execution. We can setup a flag (such as HttpContext.Items["flag"]) to tell the filter, in this way, we don't need to write the body twice.