# How to Override 415 response in ASP.Net Core2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

in .net core 2.2 ,has a default json with statuscode 415 like

```
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
   "title":"Unsupported Media Type",
   "status":415,
   "traceId":"8000003e-0001-f500-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I don't know how this JSON came from.
I follow the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166761/override-415-response-in-asp-net-core) below to rewrite json

But I got a different result,It added a section to the original json . This is my Wireshark Result

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 Server:
>
> Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Mon, 06 May 2019 09:03:56 GMT

```
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
   "title":"Unsupported Media Type",
   "status":415,
   "traceId":"8000002c-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
{
   "data":"this is custom message"
}
```

**Filter**:

```
public class MediaTypeResouceFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 415)
        {
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = "this is custom message" });
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, what it did was make the response not JSON. JSON does not support objects to follow each other like that. I am not an ASP.NET Core expert, but perhaps you have both the existing and the new filter enabled, and they both added their output?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen It's really not a JSON,but in wireshark result it's content-type is application/problem+json

Comment: I am still guessing that both the existing and your filter add their respective outputs, in the order of old+new. Now, a better question from here would be to ask what you really wanted to happen? Did you want to *add* your property to the existing response? Did you want to remove the old response and only respond with `{ "data": "this is custom message" }`I ask because your question seem to imply that your current response is wrong, but you haven't stated what you would consider to be correct. This makes it hard for anyone to suggest what to do.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i want to remove the old response and only repond with { "data": "this is custom message" } . I'm sure there's only one filter in my webapi

Comment: If there is no way (or too late) to clear the output before writing your own, then you will need to disable/reimplement the existing filter to make sure it doesn't output its own message first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know how this JSON came from.

When the `[ApiController]` attribute is applied to a controller, it enables [Problem details for error status codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-for-error-status-codes), which ends up with a built-in action filter being added to the MVC filter pipeline for that controller. This action filter applies to all status-codes >= 400 and produces the JSON response you've described.

> It added a section to the original json

When your `MediaTypeResouceFilter.OnResourceExecuted` code runs, the action filter I've noted above has already written JSON to the body. You write an additional JSON formatted string to the body, which just gets appended and mangles the response to be invalid JSON.

If you want to disable this problem details JSON from ever being written for responses, you can add the following to your `Startup.ConfigureServices` code to suppress the functionality:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only appending to body, and whatever was written to body before your filter executed, remained in the body.

If you [take a look at the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cancellation-and-short-circuiting) for how to implement IResource filter, you can achieve your goal with this line of code, but inside OnResourceExecuting instead:

```
context.Result = new ContentResult()
{
    Content = jsonString
};
```

The documentation states that:

> You can short-circuit the filter pipeline at any point by setting the Result property on the context parameter provided to the filter method.

if you put that code inside OnResourceExecuting.

Comment: I tried this method.but the response body won't change .<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166761/override-415-response-in-asp-net-core"> the follow </a> have the same problem

Comment: @Z.Chen Have you tried putting it into OnResourceExecuting instead? The documentation says it needs to go there.

Comment: if i put it into OnResourceExecuting instead,i can't discern the respnose statuscode. it's always 200.